# Dynamic periodic tasks - alternatives to Celery beat

Tags: django, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks, periodic-task

If one wants to set up **dynamic** and **standard** periodic tasks scheduling and in a Django project, are there any stable alternatives to celery and celery beat? (when I say dynamic I mean such thing as described [here](https://medium.com/swlh/dynamic-task-scheduling-with-django-celery-beat-f2591d52e15))

Would Dramatiq or any other schedulers, for instance, allow for such customization as dynamic user-launched schedulling of periodic tasks?

Or are there any other strategies for creating some kind of dynamic schedule with periodic tasks for Django in general ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to configure jobs in Django.

There is a good and helpful extension called django-crontab [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab). This could be something that will allow you to do what you need. This will tie in with Django specific as requested. Hope this is some help you on your alternative to Celery beats.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had the same problem with `django-celery-beat` the problem is you cannot manage the periodic tasks dynamically (changing the schedule or adding the task itself on a running celery worker), to overcome this issue you can use this library `djang-redbeat` which does exactly what you want. The only difference is the `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER` this library uses `Redis` database to store the tasks and their results.

https://pypi.org/project/django-redbeat/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [daffi](https://600apples.github.io/dafi/usage/scheduling-tasks/)

Using this library, it's possible to schedule recurring tasks and cancel them using task UUID at any time.